# Error with check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Ошибка

> PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= login' at line 2

PHP

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$db = $f3->get('DB');
$log = $db->exec("SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE $login = login AND $password = password");
```

HTML

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Input login</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Input password</td>
            <td><input type="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Log" name="log">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос ваш состоит?

Comment: $log = $db->exec(
   "SELECT name, surname FROM users
   WHERE $login = login AND $password = password");

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: PDOStatement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= login' at line 2

Comment: Не знаю, что неверно

Comment: Одинарные кавычки поставьте вокруг переменных в запросе.

Answer (score 2):

Показываю один раз

```
$sql = "SELECT name, surname, password FROM users WHERE login = ?";
$stmt = $f3->get('DB')->prepare();
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['login']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

далее сравниваем хэш пароля, полученного из формы, с полученным из бд.
```

Основные ошибки:

- exec() для селектов применять бессмысленно
- запросы, в которых участвуют переменные, всегда исполняются только через prepare()/execute()
- SQL НАДО УЧИТЬ

Ссылки для самостоятельного изучения:

- [Как работать с PDO?](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)
- [Безопасное хэширование паролей](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php)

Answer (score 0):

Пальцем в небо

```
$log = $db->exec("SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE login = $login AND password = $password");
```